# How to have custom view template in add-on in CS-Cart?

Tags: cs-cart

I simply want to replace the default view views/products/components/products_search_form.tpl with my own one. I could just replace it directly in the file structure but I want to do this via an add-on.

I've placed my customised template in: addon/my-addon/views/products/components/products_search_form.tpl but obviously that is not enough.

I've looked at the CS-Cart tutorials but none of them seem to quite relate to this case e.g. they are about hook templates or templates in blocks.

Thanks.

Update:

I found this documentation (for 4.0): http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.0.x/addons/hooking/tpl_hooks.html which says i can achieve this by placing a template with the same name under /overrides - matching the same file path as  the one I want to replace. However; this does not work. (I am on 4.3.10 but I doubt this is the problem).

Answer (score 0):

OK. The answer was as above - and remember to clear the cache by appending: &ctpl&cc to the request.